# Fastest way to reach other end?

Tags: derivatives

There is circular pool. A man can walk twice as fast as he can swim. How should he plan his journey so that he can reach the diametrically opposite point the fastest ?

My approach :

Let him walk (with speed $2s$) for a distance $r\theta$ along the curvature of pool and then swim (with speed $s$) across the chord with length $2r\sin (\frac{\pi -\theta}{2})$ ($\theta$ in radians)

The function of time in terms of $\theta$ and speed will be :

$t = \frac{r\theta}{2s} + \frac{2r\cos\frac{\theta}{2}}{s}$

Differentiating with respect to $\theta$ :

$\frac{dt}{d\theta} = \frac{r}{2s} - \frac{r sin \frac{\theta}{2}}{s}$

Now equating it equal to $zero$ we get :

$\sin \frac{\theta}{2} = \frac{1}{2}$

$\implies$ $\theta = \frac{\pi}{3}$

Therefore he must cover a distance of $\frac{r \pi}{3}$ along the circle and for the remaining, swim along the chord.

Am I right ? My apologies, due to low rep I can't embed a diagram.

Comment: your distances are wrong from the beginning. You have found the longest way to walk around the pool then swim back to the starting point.

Comment: Oh, my bad, in chord length, the angle should be $\pi - \theta$

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you’re off by a factor of two in your last step: if $\cos \frac{\theta}{2} = -\frac{1}{2}$, then $\theta = \pm\frac{4\pi}3$. This is more than halfway around the circle, so consistent with the other answers you’ve gotten, the man shouldn’t swim at all.

Second, when seeking a local minimum of a function by finding points at which its derivative is zero, remember that you also need to check that you indeed have a minimum at those points and not a maximum or inflection point. As it turns out, $t(\theta)$ has a local *maximum* at $\frac{4\pi}3$. It does have a minimum at $-\frac{4\pi}3$, but $t$ is negative there, so that solution gets rejected on physical grounds (besides the negative time, the direction in which he goes around the pool shouldn’t matter).

Answer (score 0):

The walking distance around half the pool of diameter $d$ is $d * \pi$/2. if the time it takes to go a distance x is t, then time it takes him to swim across is $2*t*d$ and the time it takes him to walk around to that point is $t*d*\pi/2$.  Since $\pi/2$ is less than 2, it is faster to walk around half the pool than it is to swim across it.  If you start talking about just chordal distances, the advantages of walking simply increase.

Answer (score 0):

Let's put Michael's answer in other words: The half perimeter of the pool is only $\pi/2 \approx 1.57$ times larger than the diameter. Hence, if the man walks twice as fast as he can swim, he will be better off walking all the way. In order to consider swimming as a profitable alternative, his walking speed should be less than $1.57$ times his swimming speed.